# Converting bytes32 to uint256 in solidity

Tags: solidity

How to go about converting a bytes32 variable to an uint256 variable in solidity? A straight forward conversion is not possible since when I converted the bytes32 variable which has a value of 99 to uint256.

uint256(0x3939000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

I get the result

25882542651938552044065725088383013338356811605330942117523409242735587098624

Comment: Do you want to support only strings which represent decimal numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that `0x393900...00` represents `99` followed by 30 zeros.

In order to represent `99`, you need to use `0x00...003939`, or simply `0x3939`.

If you do insist on supporting it in the other direction (because this is indeed how `bytes32` stores ASCII strings), then note that `0x393800...00`, for example, will be converted to `89` instead of `98`.

In order to do it this way, replace `i * 8` with `248 - i * 8` in the code below.

---

In order to handle decimal strings, you can use this:

```
function asciiToInteger(bytes32 x) public pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 y;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        uint256 c = (uint256(x) >> (i * 8)) & 0xff;
        if (48 <= c && c <= 57)
            y += (c - 48) * 10 ** i;
        else
            break;
    }
    return y;
}
```

In order to handle also hexadecimal strings, you can add this:

```
        else if (65 <= c && c <= 90)
            y += (c - 65 + 10) * 10 ** i;
        else if (97 <= c && c <= 122)
            y += (c - 97 + 10) * 10 ** i;
```